# Old password is retained by Google Chrome password manager when changing password for site, because it assigns passwords to exact URLs

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management

I recently changed my password for a website, and logged in with the new password, which caused Chrome to save it. When I tried to log in later, however, it failed.

After examining the password manager entries, it turned out that the new password had been saved for http://example.com/index.html, but there was also an entry for http://example.com that had the old password. Both URLs give the same page, by the way.

I needed to copy the new password to the clipboard, and login for http://example.com, in order to update the password for http://example.com. Is this the only way to do it, or is there a more graceful workaround for this problem?

**Edit:** To explain why I don't like my solution, it's manual and laborious. It consists of the following steps:

1. Go to the site's page for changing the password.
2. Most sites ask you for your current password, and because I don't remember the password, I need to open Settings->Password Manager, and find the password.
3. I need to click a button that has "Show password" to actually show it.
4. I need to copy it to clipboard, and paste it.
5. After entering the new password, the password is not updated, so I need to logout, and login again with the new password.
6. At some time later, the login **mysteriously fails** (and at the time I didn't know why).
7. At that point, I head for the Password Manager dialog again, and I find out there is **another URL** that has the old password.
8. I need to change it, so I find the URL that has my new password, click the "Show password" again, and I copy it to the clipboard.
9. Finally, I login with the new password, while being careful to make sure that the URL is the one I wish to update (I might have closed that tab and reopened, and the URL might be the one that has the new password anyways - yes, it has happened to me too). Finally, this fixes it for that URL.
10. If, for some reason, there are other URLs with the old password, I need to repeat that for each one of them, or I would have the mysterious failure again later in the future.

I'm asking if there is a way to do it in less steps, or less time than that. I mean the password manager basically fails you if you don't know how it works. Imagine a user who doesn't know all these steps, his login fails, and he's stuck.

Comment: @DaveRook You can not edit web site url in settings/passwords , you can only delete whole entry or can view passwords

Comment: `www.example.com` is same as `www.example.com/index.html` but password manger treating `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/index.html` as 2 separate URLS

Answer (score 3):

1. go to `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
2. Locate Login Data file
3. Copy it some where else
4. Download http://sqlitebrowser.org
5. Install and Browse data (go to login table)
6. Save it and replace with origional one (make a backup of origional file incase something went wrong ;) )

   [image: Enjoy]

Comment: I don't really think this is a "more graceful workaround" OP wanted.